# How to handle token expiration?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

How should one handle the expiration of user tokens in Firebase?

What I have thought of is verifying before each network call if the token expired and if so, then send the user to the Login View Controller.

I am pretty sure that this is not the way to do it, though, because it requires too much code repetition.

How can one 'listen' for the expiration of the token?

Comment: Firebase refreshes authentication tokens automatically, if that's what you're wondering.  There's not much need to do this yourself, except in special cases.

Comment: @DougStevenson so they don't really expire? What is the purpose of them then? Does it mean that if the token expires, the user will be able to use the app without logging in again? Thanks!

Comment: Automatic refresh only works in the situations documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#the_user_lifecycle